# Etymology of 'Space' as applied to inter-planetary or inter-galactic separation

Tags: etymology

The word 'space' literally means 'emptiness' or 'expanse'.
When did the term begin to be used to the emptiness between planets/stars/galaxies?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=space

Comment: I would suggest that 'space', used astronomically, means that which _contains_ the items in the universe rather than that which separates them. Many theories suggest, and it is logical to accept the general hypothesis, that 'space' (the astronomical term) is a construct, not a vacancy and is the medium _which communicates light_, rather than the emptiness through which it travels.

Answer (score 2):

From **1582**:

> Consider the huge substance of the earth, so heauie and great as it is: How could it so stand stably in the **space** as it doth, if GODS goodnesse reserued it not so for vs to trauell on?

That citation is from *The Second Book of Homilies*, sermon 17 [(text)](http://www.anglicanlibrary.org/homilies/bk2hom17.htm) [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Books_of_Homilies).  It is the oldest citation in the *OED* under the eighth sense:

> **8.** The expanse in which celestial objects are situated; the physical universe (excluding celestial objects) beyond the earth's atmosphere, consisting of near vacuum with small amounts of gas and dust. Frequently with modifying word.

If you look through the text of the sermons in *The Second Book*, you'll see that **space** usually refers to *time,* as in this quote from the 7th sermon:

> there fell no rain vpon the earth for the **space** of three yeares

In fact, the first branch of the *OED*'s definitions, and the earliest citations contained therein, refer to "space" meaning time, although the word had also been used to mean physical distance as early as circa 1350.

**Outer space** doesn't come until much later, first appearing in **1842** in Emmeline Charlotte E . Stuart Wortley's poem *The Maiden of Moscow*:

> All Earth in madness moved,—o'erthrown, To outer space—driven—racked—undone!